# Get the status of service running on remote computer using Python

Tags: python-3.x, service, remote-server

I am using python 3.
I am  able to see status of any service running on my own machine using psutil package, but dont know how to check the same on some remote computer. I am able to connect to remote computer using wmi package.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to check services status of remotes machines is using scripts on their side and to send data via websockets to the main PC (https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html).
In this case a WebSocket's deployed server is required.

If there is an more easiest way I would like to know it too.